# What is causing the parsing error for forms on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read the React documentations for forms:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_forms.asp

However, I am continuing to get a parsing error starting on the line:

```
<form onsubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

What about the form syntax is causing this error in my code?:

- *Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?*

```
import React from "react";

class JoinUs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            name:"",
            email:"",
            website:"",
            nearestLocation:""
            }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Join Us</h1>
             <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                Name
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="name"
                    required
                    />
              </label>
                <br/>
                <label>
                    Email
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        name="email"
                        required
                    />
                </label>
                <br/>
  
                <label>
                    Website
                   <input
                    type="url"
                    value={this.state.website}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="website"
                    required
                   />
                </label>
                <br/>

                <label>
                    Nearest Location
                <select value= {this.state.nearestLocation} onChange={this.handleChange} name="nearestLocation">
                    <option value="austin">Austin, TX</option>
                    <option value="brooklyn">Brooklyn, NY</option>
                    <option value="los-angeles">Los Angeles, CA</option>
                    <option value="new-york">New York, NY</option>
                    <option value="portland">Portland, OR</option>
                    <option value="san-fran">San Francisco, CA</option>
                    <option value="seattle">Seattle, WA</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                </label>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
             </form>     
        );
    }
}


export default JoinUs;
```

Comment: put the h1 inside the form, or wrap the heading and form with div or React.Fragment

Comment: The message tells you exactly what the problem is *and how to fix it*; being more disciplined with indentation would probably help in spotting it.

Comment: Solved by adding opening adding <br> tags..

Answer (score 0):

In React you can't have more than 1 parent tag in your return statement, and if you need to, you can always enclose them in a React.Fragment

```
<>
  <h1></h1>
  <form></form>
</>
```